# SGML Parser for Python 3?

Tags: xml-parsing, python-3.x, sgml

I have some documents that are structured using SGML, and I have a DTD file which describes this structure.

Can someone recommend a Python-3 compatible library or module to me to parse this data?  For Python 2.x my Google-fu seems to turn up [SGMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/sgmllib.html), but that of course is now deprecated (and outright removed from Py3k).

Many seem to suggest `lxml`, but that is not an option for me due to dependency issues.

I know `BeautifulSoup` is great for messy markup, but A) last I heard it wasn't py3k compatible, and B) this content is well-structured.

Answer (score 3):

BeautifulSoup is deprecated. Use the replacement instead, which is Py3k compatible:

- [BeautifulSoup4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4/)